# Update news items like on FaceBook

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dynamic

I'm working on a website that will have a page with the latest (short) news items. Users can posts comments and add like's on these items. Just as the FaceBook profile page.

I want this update to be dynamic and I use jQuery. I left out as much code as posible, because this question is more about the process then the actual code.

But the basic code setup is:

```
<ul id="news_list">
    <li id="1">
        //news item inner html
    </li>

    <li id="2">
        //news item inner html
        <input type="text" name="comment"/> //example when the user is adding a comment to the post
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have the following process (runs every 10 seconds the update_news function):

- the update_news function will call the php page which returns the last 10 items as HTML.
- the result HTML is then used to replace the list's HTML.

The problem with this process is that the whole list is getting reloaded every 10 seconds, and that the comment input field (that's embedded in the li and shows up when a user wants to comment to the news item) is also replaced, and by doing so, removing the input field from the html.

I thought of maybe returning a JSON object that holds a array with the items, then check the items in the page with the ones returned? But this seems a bit of overkill..

Or when updating, remember the item where the comment input is (and hold the input value). renew the news list, find the item where the comment input was and place it back.

Does someone know a process to update the news items so that only the parts that are new of the news items are replaced and not the whole inner HTML of the ul tag?

Comment: You can send last timestamp and get only data after that time.

Comment: Good point. But it's impossible with the setup I use news_item -> comments. What happens if the news isn't updated but the comments are? Or I also have to set the timestamp of the news item when a comment changes or is added to the news item.

Comment: This is just for new records, and for comments you need to setup different event listener. And, of course, for traffic decrease, better to use JSON.

Comment: Try taking a look at how Facebook does the trick. My guess would be as Olexandr says, just get the new data. Have it returned as JSON object, iterate through it and use and ID to inject new data at the corresponding item/ with matching ID.